Bulk download envelope responses in docusign
As an admin I have sent envelopes to multiple recipients in several batches.
Is there a way I can download the completed pdf's in bulk for that particular batch.
I am using bulk send to send out many envelopes at once.
It would be really useful if there's a way in which i can do so.
I didn't find anything about it in the API documentation related to my use case

One option is to use a tool called Docusign Retrieve.
Docusign Retrieve, a Windows based tool, retrieves a copy of envelopes and documents that were sent from a user account. The original envelopes and documents remain in the Docusign account.
Now, this tool my cost money, so the other option is for you to build an API integration that does the same thing.
You will have to first make an API call to get all the envelopes you're interested in. This can be done using this example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes/
Then, you would have to loop through all these envelopes and download the documents one by one. This can be done using this example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/

I have about 2.5k envelopes per user so I am thinking of creating an API that will download it one by one. Will it exceed any burst rate limit or API limit by doing so. Thank you

Yes, if you make the API calls too quickly it will. I suggest you add some delays or do it in smaller batches
